# Efficient way to convert a column of symbol type in DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb

How can I remove the suffix from '.SH' suffix and prefix it with 6? Is there any efficient way to update the records?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a table looks like this:

```
t = table(1..50000 as id, take(['600000.SH', '600001.SH', '600002.SH', '000002.SZ', '000001.SZ'], 500000) as x);
```

You can try the following three methods:

```
update t set x = iif(right(x, 3)=='.SH', take("1", size(x)) + left(x, 6), take("0", size(x)+left(x, 6)))
update t set x = iif(right(x, 3)=='.SH', "1"+string(left(x, 6)), "6"+string(left(x, 6)))
update t set x = iif(right(x, 3)=='.SH', "1".add(left(x, 6)), "6".add(left(x, 6)))
```